# LogParser crashes without error in C#

Tags: c#, .net, crash, logparser

I'm trying to implement MS LogParser in a C# application. This compiles fine but inexplicably crashes on the logQuery.ExecuteBatch() method. The try/catch block doesn't catch it unless I specifically malform the szQuery, which suggests that everything is working as it should, I'm just not getting any output.

Any thoughts on why it might be crashing or where I might find some logging?

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using FolderLoggingLib;
using MSUtil;

namespace ConsoleApplication20
{
    class Program 
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //refLog = new BinaryInputFormat();
            LogQueryClass logQuery = new LogQueryClass();
            ICOMCSVOutputContext output = new COMCSVOutputContextClass();
            ILogParserInputContext parse = new BinaryInputFormat();

`string szFileName = @"E:\Programming\FolderLogging\2012-05-13.fbl";
        string szQuery = "SELECT Folder, User, Record, DB, TO_LOCALTIME(Timestamp) AS DateTime, Operation, Checked FROM " + szFileName + " ORDER BY DateTime DESC";
        try
        {
            logQuery.ExecuteBatch(szQuery, parse, output);
        }
        catch
        {
        };           
    }
}`

}

Comment: try catch(Exception ex) to see what exception you get and post the details.

Comment: Tried - it never reaches the catch block, the program just dies on the logQuery.ExecuteBatch() method.

Answer (score 1):

Use Execute instead of ExecuteBatch:

```
MSUtil.ILogRecordset RecordSet = logQuery.Execute(query, oInputFormat)
```

If you want to export to CSV in your sample code you need to change the query by adding INTO output_file_name and run ExecuteBatch:

```
string szQuery = "SELECT Folder, User, Record, DB, TO_LOCALTIME(Timestamp) AS DateTime, Operation,  Checked **INTO c:\out\out.csv** FROM " + szFileName + " ORDER BY DateTime DESC";
```